# Install driver SMC2662W Wireless USB card and Corega 11 Mini

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, usb

Greeting:

Well now I come to ask a boon.

As you will see in the title I'm asking for help to install some drivers and Corega USB SMC2662W 11 Mini ...

MI lsusb is as follows:

ricardo-root @ desktop: / home / ricardo # lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 090c: 6300 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0d5c: a001 SMC Networks, Inc. SMC2662W (v1) EZ Connect Wireless 802.11b Adapter [Atmel AT76C503A]

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 07aa: 0011 Corega K.K. USB-11 mini Wireless LAN

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093A: 2622 Pixart Imaging, Inc.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Here it is assumed that the driver is listed but after a while you connect any wireless network does not appear ..

I've tried everything ..

I searched the Internet solutions for installing this type of wireless tarketas but none came to me.

My version is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

I please ask you a help for this problem ..

Thank you

PS: Sorry for my bad English

PD2: Hello:

I did what you asked me and I came out here the results of the two commands that did me to put ..

root@ricardo-desktop:/home/ricardo# modinfo at76c50x-usb | grep

A001alias:          usb:v0D5CpA001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*

root@ricardo-desktop:/home/ricardo# sudo modprobe at76c50x-usb && dmesg | grep at76

[  137.906977] Atmel at76x USB Wireless LAN Driver 0.17 loading
[  138.104111] usb 2-1: firmware atmel_at76c503-i3861.bin not found!
[  138.104119] usb 2-1: you may need to download the firmware from http://developer.berlios.de/projects/at76c503a/
[  138.104133] at76c50x-usb: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -2
[  138.104172] usbcore: registered new interface driver at76c50x-usb

PD2:

I get this error when testing wireless card SMC:

ricardo - root @ desktop : / home / ricardo # iwlist scanning

wlan0 Interface does not support scanning : Device or resource busy

the Interface does not support scanning .

eth0 Interface does not support scanning .

PD 3:

root@ricardo-desktop:/home/ricardo# iw list

```
Wiphy phy1

Band 1:

    Frequencies:

        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps
        * 5.5 Mbps
        * 11.0 Mbps
max # scan SSIDs: 1
max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * managed
     * monitor
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * monitor
interface combinations are not supported
Supported commands:
     * new_interface
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * new_beacon
     * new_station
     * new_mpath
     * set_mesh_params
     * set_bss
     * authenticate
     * associate
     * deauthenticate
     * disassociate
     * join_ibss
     * join_mesh
     * set_tx_bitrate_mask
     * action
     * frame_wait_cancel
     * set_wiphy_netns
     * set_channel
     * set_wds_peer
     * Unknown command (84)
     * Unknown command (87)
     * Unknown command (85)
     * Unknown command (89)
     * Unknown command (92)
     * connect
     * disconnect
Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * managed: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * AP: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * mesh point: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * P2P-client: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * P2P-GO: 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
     * Unknown mode (10): 0x0000 0x0010 0x0020 0x0030 0x0040 0x0050 0x0060 0x0070 0x0080 0x0090 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0 0x00e0 0x00f0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x0040 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0
     * managed: 0x0040 0x00d0
     * AP: 0x0000 0x0020 0x0040 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x0000 0x0020 0x0040 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0
     * mesh point: 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0
     * P2P-client: 0x0040 0x00d0
     * P2P-GO: 0x0000 0x0020 0x0040 0x00a0 0x00b0 0x00c0 0x00d0
     * Unknown mode (10): 0x0040 0x00d0
```

PD4:

root@ricardo-desktop:/home/ricardo/Descargas/atmel-firmware_1.3-4_all
/lib/firmware#

dmesg | grep -e at76 -e wlan

[  119.829345] Atmel at76x USB Wireless LAN Driver 0.17 loading

[  119.869485] usb 2-1: using firmware atmel_at76c503-i3861.bin (version 
0.90.0-44)

[  119.871410] at76c50x-usb 2-1:1.0: downloading external firmware

[  119.966949] usbcore: registered new interface driver at76c50x-usb

[  120.021551] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

[  120.022119] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

[  616.516723] Modules linked in: arc4 at76c50x_usb mac80211 cfg80211 bnep rfcomm bluetooth parport_pc ppdev snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib gspca_pac7302 snd_hwdep gspca_main snd_pcm i915 videodev snd_seq_midi binfmt_misc snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq drm_kms_helper snd_timer drm snd_seq_device gpio_ich i2c_algo_bit snd psmouse lpc_ich soundcore snd_page_alloc serio_raw shpchp video mac_hid lp parport usb_storage r8169 mii pata_acpi floppy

[  636.012419] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 7612.649341] at76c50x-usb 2-1:1.0: disconnected

[ 7614.410058] at76c50x-usb 2-1:1.0: downloading internal firmware

[ 7617.103054] at76c50x-usb 2-1:1.0: downloading external firmware

[ 7617.197294] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

[ 7619.197141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these two terminal commands: `modinfo at76c50x-usb | grep A001` and also: `sudo modprobe at76c50x-usb && dmesg | grep at76` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Edit commands the question you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the version of the driver included in Ubuntu 12.04 covers your device but the needed firmware is not installed. There is a package we can extract the files from. Please download this file to your desktop: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/a/atmel-firmware/atmel-firmware_1.3-4_all.deb Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' In the resulting folder, named `atmel-firmware_1.3-4_all`, right-click the package data.tar.gz and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/atmel-firmware_1.3-4_all/data/lib/firmware
sudo cp *.bin  /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -r at76c50x-usb  &&  sudo modprobe at76c50x-usb
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Hello : Well try what you did and it worked .. But The Problem Is That I do not detect any network around mine .. That Is Sorry for the ignorance in Such issues , but to detect all networks as it Becomes

Comment: Please reboot and then let us see: `dmesg | grep -e at76 -e wlan` and also: `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: Hello.

Try the wireless card and if I went Corega available networks .. but the problem was that not connect.

Try the SMC2662W wireless card and assumes that appeared me but no network available network appears ..

What can I do about it?

Comment: I thought we were working on the SMC. Am I mistaken? How about the diagnostics I requested above? Is it possible that the SMC is old enough that it doesn't do WPA? Is it possible that all the nearby networks are encrypted with WPA/WPA2? Find out about your card with: `iw list`.

Comment: You are not wrong ..
As I said above if we are working with SMC, because I think I said already Corega if I detect network but not connected to any ..
The networks you want to connect work with WEP
I put up what I got command

Comment: And the other command? `dmesg | grep -e at76 -e wlan`

Comment: Here I upload a screenshot .

Where is the pointer is supposed to have networks appear .. but does not appear ..  http://screenshot.net/94xx3i2?es